How did Borden avoid blame by telling the FBI about Oppenheimer, instead of the AEC?
In Oppenheimer (2023), Lewis Strauss is revealing the identity of the person behind the charges
against Robert Oppenheimer to the Senate Aide:

Lewis Strauss: He was a rabid anti-Communist named Borden. He wrote to
the FBI demanding they take action.
Senate Aide: The FBI? Why not go to the AEC, direct?
Lewis Strauss: Why get caught holding the knife yourself?

It’s a way of saying Borden didn’t want to be directly blamed
for acting against Oppenheimer.
How did Borden avoid blame by telling the FBI about Oppenheimer, instead of the AEC?

I assume from the context that if he goes to the FBI he would be anonymous (outside of the FBI) rather than have to reveal himself to the AEC where Oppy was an advisor.
